# Replace values with NA where date is greater then... with R

Tags: r

I tried to create exact sample data but failed, here is attempt:

```
data1 <- data.frame(date=as.Date(as.character(c("01-03-2015","01-04-2015","01-05-2015")),"%d-%m-%Y"), Val=rnorm(3,1,1))
data2 <- data.frame(date=c(NA,"",NA), Val=rnorm(3,1,1))
data3 <- data.frame(date=as.Date(as.character(c("01-09-2015","01-10-2015","01-11-2015")),"%d-%m-%Y"), Val=rnorm(3,1,1))

do.call(cbind, list(data1,data2,data3))
```

The sample data should look like this (I tried to bind with `rbind` but it fails to me for unknown reason).

```
        date        Val 
1 2015-03-01 -0.8496063 
2 2015-04-01  1.5014609    
3 2015-05-01  0.7923492 
4        <NA> 1.6646475
5             1.1976965   # empty string in column date
6        <NA> 0.9105403   # NA in column date 
7 2015-09-01  0.6214811
8 2015-10-01  1.1314259
```

What I would like to do is to replace all values of column Val with `NA`, where in column date, dates are greater then `2015-09-01`

Here is not exactly the sample data I have (It matters whether empty string or NA, these properties must stay intact).

```
Sampdata <- data.frame(date=c(as.Date(as.character(c("01-03-2015","01-04-2015","01-05-2015")),"%d-%m-%Y"),"NA","NA","NA",
                          as.Date(as.character(c("01-08-2015","01-09-2015")),"%d-%m-%Y")), Val=rnorm(8,1,1))


Sampdata$Val <- ifelse(Sampdata$date>=(as.Date(as.character("2015-09-01"))),NA,Sampdata$Val)
```

The above solution fails, since it replaces with NA also those rows where the column date contains NA and empty string.

Desired solution:

```
            date        Val 
1 2015-03-01 -0.8496063 
2 2015-04-01  1.5014609    
3 2015-05-01  0.7923492 
4        <NA> 1.6646475
5             1.1976965  
6        <NA> 0.9105403  
7 2015-09-01  NA
8 2015-10-01  NA
```

**EDIT:**

So let's correct the sample date to this: (no empty string)

```
Sampdata <- data.frame(date=c(as.Date(as.character(c("01-03-2015","01-04-2015","01-05-2015")),"%d-%m-%Y"),"NA","NA","NA",
                          as.Date(as.character(c("01-08-2015","01-09-2015")),"%d-%m-%Y")),   Val=rnorm(8,1,1))
```

The proposed solution:

```
indx <- as.Date(Sampdata$date) >= '2015-09-01'
Sampdata$Val[indx & !is.na(indx)] <- NA
Sampdata
```

Gives on my pc this:

```
        date        Val
1 2015-03-01  1.4437853
2 2015-04-01 -0.1695267
3 2015-05-01  0.5083815
4       <NA>         NA
5       <NA>         NA
6       <NA>         NA
7 2015-08-01  0.3026487
8 2015-09-01         NA
```

Comment: Have you tried it using the `dput` data on the post.  I was not using the `Sampdata`

Comment: @akrun: yes, it works on your dput data.

Comment: The reason it fails when you `rbind` is in the help file. "...It then takes the classes of the columns from the first data frame...". You get an error because `rbind` tries to create a `Date` object from `data2$date` which results in the same error as if you do `as.Date("")`.

Comment: @Max Please check how you created the `NA`.  It is `"NA"` and not real `NA`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
 indx <- as.Date(df$date) >= '2015-09-01'
 df$Val[indx & !is.na(indx)] <- NA
 df
 #      date        Val
 #1 2015-03-01 -0.8496063
 #2 2015-04-01  1.5014609
 #3 2015-05-01  0.7923492
 #4       <NA>  1.6646475
 #5             1.1976965
 #6       <NA>  0.9105403
 #7 2015-09-01         NA
 #8 2015-10-01         NA
```

#### Update

I would create the `Sampdata` with real `NA`s instead of `"NA"`

```
 Sampdata <- data.frame(date=c(as.Date(as.character(c("01-03-2015",
 "01-04-2015","01-05-2015")),"%d-%m-%Y"),NA,NA,NA,
  as.Date(as.character(c("01-08-2015",
"01-09-2015")), "%d-%m-%Y")), Val=rnorm(8,1,1))

  indx <-Sampdata$date >='2015-09-01'
  Sampdata$Val[indx & !is.na(indx)] <- NA
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("2015-03-01", "2015-04-01", "2015-05-01", 
"<NA>", "", "<NA>", "2015-09-01", "2015-10-01"), Val = c(-0.8496063, 
1.5014609, 0.7923492, 1.6646475, 1.1976965, 0.9105403, 0.6214811, 
1.1314259)), .Names = c("date", "Val"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

Answer (score 6):

you can combine the two steps from akrun to one single line

```
df$Val[df$date >= '2015-09-01'] <- NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
is.na(Sampdata$Val) <- Sampdata$date >= '2015-09-01'
```